# BigQuery, SLAs and support

Tags: google-bigquery

I am in the process of evaluating whether [BigQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigQuery) could be a good choice for some data processing we want to run periodically.

I do appreciate that BigQuery is still under heavy development and that improvements and fixes are likely to happen pretty often.

I woud like to know what would be the process should a release break a previously working process. I have read the [SLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement), but they seem to be more oriented to downtime, rather than regression issues/bugs. Is there an option for paid support with SLAs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most commercial services, Google applies rigorous build and test processes to ensure quality. If you have specific support requirements, we encourage you to [contact Google's Cloud Platform sales team](http://cloud.google.com/contact.html) to discuss our premier offering.

Comment: Hi Michael, BigQuery sounds very interesting. However, some of the questions posted to SO regarding BQ are vague and/or off-topic. Would it be possible on your [developer support page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/support) to emphasize that SO is for programming questions and perhaps to offer a contact channel for non-programming Qs?